# Joining pyspark dataframes on exact match of a whole word in a string, pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, one that has an address column that's an entire string of words, human-entered data, and university addresses(df) and I want to extract city information from that. So I use another master city data(world_countries) to identify which of these cities are present in the string and use that in a new column.

Initially, I attempted this join with a contains() which gave me bad values as it is searching for even the characters and lookalikes like below

```
df = df.join(world_countries, df.address.contains(world_countries.city), how='left')
```

Gave me some results like this:

[image: result]

I understand what I need, I need to join whole words in strings, maybe something like a regexp string will help. but I don't have a said pattern to match on, I need the match to be on the entire column on a dataframe.

I can go the long way around, split the address into multiple columns and left join on each to find the match but that's just a lot and doesn't seem programmatically correct as well.

Please suggest a better way to do this, esp by joining on regexp on the entire column. Here is the code.

```
def pubmed2(pubmed_clean, worldcities):
    df = pubmed_clean.selectExpr("AffiliationInfo as address").filter((F.col('address').isNotNull())).distinct()
    w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
    df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w))
    df= df.filter(F.col("row_num")<=100)
    df = df.select([F.lower(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
    world_cities=worldcities.select([F.lower(col(c)).alias(c) for c in worldcities.columns])
    df = udf(df, world_cities)
    final = df.dropDuplicates()
    return final

def udf(df,world_cities):
    world_countries = (world_cities.selectExpr("country").distinct())#.withColumnRenamed(entity,"entity"))
    df = (df.join(world_countries, df.address.contains(world_countries.country), how='left'))
    world_countries = (world_cities.selectExpr("city").distinct())
    df = df.join(world_countries,df.address.contains(world_countries.city), how='left')
    
return df
```

Sample data:

Centre for Primary Health Care, University of Basel, Kantonsspital Baselland, Rheinstrasse 26, 4410, Liestal, Switzerland.

Department of Family Medicine, Healthcare System Gangnam Center, Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, 06236, Republic of Korea.

Department of Medical-Surgical Nursing, School of Nursing & Midwifery, Shahid Beheshti University of Medical Sciences, Tehran, Iran.

Department of Nursing, Federal University of the Valleys of Jequitinhonha and Mucuri, Diamantina, Minas Gerais, Brazil. Laboratory of Bioengineering, Federal University of Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte,Minas Gerais, Brazil.

Sensory Science Centre, Division of Food, Nutrition and Dietetics, School of Biosciences, The University of Nottingham, Sutton Bonington Campus, Leicestershire, LE12 5RD, UK.

University of Michigan Medical School, Ann Arbor, MI, USA.

Comment: cant you not split the address column using delimiter and only extract specific index that contain the city? And whats the significance for world_countries?

Comment: Please provide reproducible code with sample data for the 2 dataframes so we test and provide the best solutions

Comment: updated with full code. world_countries is a dataframe which has all cities in the world along with countries

Comment: @Monsta Can you give an example of a bad match?

Comment: please provide some sample data with say 10 records for the 2 dataframes as well. and expected output

Comment: @Ronak , all of those you see in the image are bad matches except those which have full city name.

Comment: https://simplemaps.com/static/data/world-cities/basic/simplemaps_worldcities_basicv1.75.zip
 cities dataset can be found here

Comment: @Monsta Got it, posted my answer for a small sample, let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["Centre for Primary Health Care, University of Basel, Kantonsspital Baselland, Rheinstrasse 26, 4410, Liestal, Switzerland","1"],\
                        ["Department of Family Medicine, Healthcare System Gangnam Center, Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, 06236, Republic of Korea","2"],\
                        ["Intentional Bad Record(Seoul), Korea", "3"]])\
  .toDF("address", "row_num");

world_countries = spark.createDataFrame([["Seoul","Republic of Korea"],["Liestal","Switzerland"]]).toDF("City", "Countries");

df=df.withColumn("address",F.regexp_replace(F.col("address"), " ", "")).withColumn("asArray", F.split("address", ","));

df.join(world_countries, F.array_contains(df["asArray"], world_countries["City"]), how='left').show()
```

As you can see the record with row_num=3 contains the word "Seoul" within the first string, but won't be matched with Seoul as "a city" during the Join.

Input/Output:

[image: Input/Output]

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you so much, it works great for extracting whole words. I am trying to further extract university names as well by using reference words like [college, university]. i tried using array_contains but it doesn't work as it matches only with whole words. i would want it to work like contains but for each elements of the array and then return me that entire string. Any suggestions would be great!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: PS without exploding the array though